# How to parse JSON in PHP and pass it to Javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, twitter

This is my goal: Use twitter api to populate some slides with recent tweets without reloading the page.

The way I have it right now is this: I'm making an ajax call every few seconds from a javascript on my page to a php page. The php page sets up and authenticates a connection to Twitter and gets a responce in JSON format. Now here is my problem, the JSON responces I get are all mix and match some are arrays some are stdClass objects. Ideally I would like to pass this JSON directly to Javascript as an object, so inside Javascript I can do something like this, jsonresponce->statuses->text.

Keeping that in mind here is the same structure I described but in code:

Front End->

```
// JavaScript Document

function AJAXToTwitter(){
console.log("making ajax call");
$.ajax({
    url: '../php/twiter-stream.php',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(responce) {
        $.each(responce, function(i, obj){
            $(".LiveSlide1 .text").html(obj.text);
        });

        console.log("ajax call successful");
    },
    error: function(errors) {
      console.log("ajax call failed");
    }

})
}

$(document).ready(AJAXToTwitter);
```

Back End ->

```
//PHP Document

<?php
require "../vendor/autoload.php";
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

$consumerKey = "iNol________________n5uVZcAB";
$consumerSecret = "o_______________________l1_J";
$accessToken = "142480736-jlOVy___________________________________tm5b7ZN";
$accessTokenSecret = "K___________________________________________wF__V";

function getToken( $apiKey, $apiKeySecret, $axToken, $axTokenSecret ) {
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth( $apiKey, $apiKeySecret, $axToken, $axTokenSecret );
return $connection;
}

$connection = getToken($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $accessToken, 
$accessTokenSecret);

$urlQuery = "#WebDesign";
$search = $connection->get("search/tweets", ["q" => $urlQuery]);



echo (json_encode($search));

?>
```

The problem here is that I think that the responce in the case of search/tweets query is a class so json_encode produces a string and I'm unable to use $.each function. The exact error in Chrome Dev Tools Console says

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '70806' in 
 {"statuses":[{"created_at":"Sun Jun 11 17:15:40 +0000 .......
```

and it goes on to spit out the whole json string that I encoded.

My question is what is the proper way to handle JSON in general when dealing with an API like this, should I just avoid using PHP and do a direct call from JavaScript? Should I manually extract every responce and encode it in a smaller, handmade json? Or is there a way to just pass the response unmodified back to javascript?

Comment: Best practice will be to handle the JSON object from the start in JavaScript. There are ways, but they're hacky and you'll always find bugs you need to work around like this.

Comment: @Z.Bagley I see, but what about doing it in PHP? I would rather have a cleaner more complex method rather than a hacking a messier one that's easy.

Comment: @TimAkgayev Specify `dataType: 'json'` explicitly in `$.ajax` settings. This will ensure the `responce` in `success` function will be a JavaScript object.

Answer (score 0):

So after some trial and error I got it to work. The PHP file is the same, in the JavaScript I had to do this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../php/twiter-stream.php',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(responce) {

        //added this line to parse the json string into JS object
        var parsedJSON = JSON.parse(responce);

        //now just iterating over the object to extract the info
        $.each(parsedJSON.statuses, function(i, obj) {

            var slideIndex = (i + 1) % 7;
             $(".LiveSlide" + slideIndex+ " .text").html(obj.text);
             $(".LiveSlide" + slideIndex+ " .Date").html(obj.created_at);
        });


        console.log("ajax call successful");
    },
    error: function(errors) {
      console.log("ajax call failed");
    }

})
```

This is the way I think it works, inside the PHP the TwitterOAuth::get() function retrieves a JSON string from the Twitter server, encodes it into a class. In order to pass it to javascript I needed to convert that class back to a string, that's done with json_encode(). Then inside the javascript we convert it back into an object using either JSON.parse() like I did here or you can also probably specify " dataType: 'json' " in the jQuery ajax call as @Joe Black suggested.